# Regex for pattern matching last instance with a range of values

Tags: regex

I need to split a string that has a character, that is repeated but only split the last **3** instances and keep the **0** to any number of instances before those **3** instances of the character.

> ex1: `"Hi@@@@there"` after regex (and splitting) `"Hi@","there"`
>
> ex2: `"Hi@@@there"` after regex (and splitting) `"Hi","there"`

Splitting on `@{3}` does not give the result I want: `"Hi","@there"`

**edit:**
I simplified my quesiton a bit; serialization and the character I am using is not relevant. I'm just interested in the regex that will get me the last **x** number in a list of y number of a repetitive list of characters. `(@{3})(\w+)` results in only returning `hi@` and the rest of the string is lost.

Comment: Not really clear what you want to achieve here. Split on `@@@` but ignore the first `@` if 4 in a row are found? i.e. your output would become `[Hi, there@, user]` instead of current result `[Hi, there, @user]`?

Comment: What's wrong with `(@{3})(\w+)`?

Comment: You do realize there is a `Serializable` interface you can implement and let `Java` serialize and de-serialize the object for you?

Comment: The problem is your serialize/deserialize.  If I have a string "@ @ @ @", then you will get "@@@@@@@@@@@@@", there is no way to know how you want that. "    @" or "@    " or "@@@@@@@@@@@@@"?

Comment: Why don't you use some combination that you know won't be in the `String`? Example: `!@;#`

Comment: I simplified my quesiton a bit; serialization and the character I am using is not relevant.  I'm just interested in the regex that will get me the last x number in a list of y number of a repetitive list of characters.  (@{3})(\w+) results in only returning hi@ and the rest of the string is lost.

Comment: @shortyyyyyyy could you update your question with the comment you wrote, so that all relevant information are together. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in Javascript, but works

```js
"Hi@@@@there".split(/@@@(?=[^@])/);  // Output = > ["Hi@", "there"]
"Hi@@@there".split(/@@@(?=[^@])/);   // Output = > ["Hi", "there"]
// Tested on win7 with Chrome 45+
```

> **(?=[^@])** ... Lookahead to check if there is no `@` after the final/splitter `@@@`

Comment: @shortyyyyyyy your welcome. :) If you could accept my answer, that would be great. (We help for the **challenge**, but also for the _"reputation"_) ;-)